# How to re-write url from nonexistant folder to file in mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to re-write both

www.mywebsite.com/example
www.mywebsite.com/example/

to

mywebsite.com/example.shtml

I use the following rules in .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.shtml -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.shtml
```

This, however, doesn't work, I get Internal Server Error. If I only have the following rules:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.shtml -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.shtml
```

then **www.mywebsite.com/example** gets re-written to **mywebsite.com/example.shtml**, but I get internal server error when I request www.mywebsite.com/example/.

Please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.shtml -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.shtml [L]
```

Clear your browser cache completely before testing this change.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks. Can you please explain why my code didn't work?

Comment: Main difference is `^(.+?)/?$` pattern that matches anything except last optional `/`

Comment: One additional question - this works fine when I deploy it to my webserver, but it turns out on localhost

localhost/mywebsite/example/

gets mapped to 

localhost/mywebsite/example.shtml/ 

and I get 404 error. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Then it is some mis-config issue on your localhost since same rule also works fine on my Apache

Comment: That is what I am thinking too, thanks a lot for the help